# Cross platform image processing library

Tags: android, ios, linux, image-processing

I'm attempting to find an image processing library that can add filters and things of this nature. Something like ImageMagick (which I have tried, but couldn't get png support and other issues specifically with Android).

The main requirement is that it produces the same images given the same filters in iOS, linux and Android.

Comment: Have you tried ImageMagick port for android? https://github.com/lilac/Android-ImageMagick

Comment: I have played with it and had varying levels of success. It's been a while, but I think the biggest issue was that I couldn't get it to build with support for anything besides jpg.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look to android package [graphics](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/package-summary.html). It contains all that you need to perform image transformation and filters and there are a lot of example on the web.

Comment: This might work as a last resort. The key will be getting it to produce the same images that you get from the other platforms.